# Android The app gets stuck without logic and for no apparent reason

Tags: android, database, sqlite, graph

I made an expense graph when I try to show it and the app gets stuck

And does not get an error an
I enclose here the code of the graph and the DataBase. Do you need more code?

This is the graph I use in the MPandroidChart library

EDIT: Could you please help me and tell me where I was wrong?
I'm trying to create a graph with all the expenses of the last month ... but for some reason I came across a problem that it does not print anything to me! I edited the message with the revised code and some explanations

```
 // get all the dates( days in this month with month) like DD.MM
public double[] getDate() {

    int month=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day=Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    double[] f;
    f= new double[day+1];

  while(day>=0)
    {
      String date = String.valueOf(month) +"."+ String.valueOf(day);
        f[day]=Double.parseDouble(date);
        day--;
    }
    return f;
}

// get Price by specific day with sum
public int getPriceDate(String id) {

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Cursor c;
    c = db.getCursorByDate(id);


        int count = getCountItem(id);
        int x = 0;
        int price11 = 0;
    int price1[] =  new int[count];

            while (x < count) {


            price1[x] = -1;
            x++;
        }

        x = 0;

     // get sum of all the day
        while (x < count) {
            if (c != null) {
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    //assuming price is an integer
                   price1[x] = c.getInt(0);//edit 4

                    price11 = price11 + price1[x];

                }

            }
            x++;
        }

    return price11;

}

// chart/ graph Daily bar chart
public void DailyChart() {


    mChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    setData(getDate().length);
    mChart.setFitBars(true);
}

// insert data to Daily Chart
private void setData(int count) {
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals = new ArrayList<>();


    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        yVals.add(new BarEntry(i,  getPriceDate(String.valueOf(getDate()[i]))));

        yVals.add(new BarEntry(i,  i));

    }

    BarDataSet set = new BarDataSet(yVals, "Data set");
    set.setColors(ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS);
    set.setDrawValues(true);

    BarData data = new BarData(set);

    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.invalidate();
    mChart.animateY(500);

}


// Get count of Specific items
public int getCountItem(String id) {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    int price = db.getCountByItem(id);
    return price;
}
```

and this my DataBase

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 11;

// Database Name
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Records_Item Purcashes";

// Contacts table name
public static final String TABLE_RECORDS = "Records";

// Contacts Table Columns names
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_PRICE = "Price";
public static final String KEY_ITEM = "Item";
public static final String KEY_DETAILS = "Details";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "DateAndTime";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_RECORDS +
            "(" +
            KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            KEY_PRICE + " INTEGER," +
            KEY_ITEM + " TEXT," +
            KEY_DETAILS + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_DATE + " TEXT" +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_RECORDS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

public void insertRecord(int price, String item, String details, String date) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_PRICE, price);
    cv.put(KEY_ITEM, item);
    cv.put(KEY_DETAILS, details);
    cv.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_RECORDS, null, cv);
}

 public Cursor getAllRecords() {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      return db.query(TABLE_RECORDS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
  }
public Cursor get1Record(String[] key) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.query(TABLE_RECORDS, key, null, null, null, null, null);
}
// Adding new contact
public void addRecord(Record record) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_ID, record.getId()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PRICE, record.getPrice()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_ITEM, record.getItem()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_DETAILS, record.getDetails()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_DATE, record.getDate()); // Contact Phone Number

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_RECORDS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
public Record getRecord(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_RECORDS, new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_PRICE,
                    KEY_ITEM, KEY_DETAILS, KEY_DATE}, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Record record = new Record(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));
    // return contact
    return record;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Record> getAllContacts() {
    List<Record> contactList = new ArrayList<Record>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_RECORDS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Record record = new Record();
            record.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            record.setPrice(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            record.setItem(cursor.getString(2));
            record.setDetails(cursor.getString(3));
            record.setDate(cursor.getString(4));

            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(record);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return contactList;
}

// Getting contacts Count
public int getRecordsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_RECORDS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    // cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Record record) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, record.getId());
    values.put(KEY_PRICE, record.getPrice());
    values.put(KEY_ITEM, record.getItem());
    values.put(KEY_DETAILS, record.getDetails());
    values.put(KEY_DATE, record.getDate());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_RECORDS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(record.getId())});
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Record record) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_RECORDS, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]
            {String.valueOf(record.getId())});
    db.close();
}
        // Deleting some Records
 public boolean deleteRecord(long id) {
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   return (db.delete(TABLE_RECORDS,KEY_ID + "=?",new String[]
  {Long.toString(id)})> 0);
 }

    public String[] getAllCountries(String KEY_PRICE) {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor =   db.query(TABLE_RECORDS, null, null, null, null, null, 
    null);

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        String[] str = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int i = 0;

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            str[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE));
            i++;
        }
        return str;
    } else {
        return new String[]{};
    }
}

public Cursor getCursor(int id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String from[] = {KEY_PRICE};//this is the edit1
    String where = KEY_ID+"=?";//this is the edit2
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)+""}; //this is the edit3
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, TABLE_RECORDS, from, where, whereArgs, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}

public Cursor getCursorByItem(String id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String Get = "select Price from Records where item  = '"+id+"'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Get ,null);
    return cursor;
}

public Cursor getCursorByDate(String id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String Get = "SELECT price FROM Records WHERE " +KEY_DATE +" LIKE '%"+id+"%'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Get ,null);
    return cursor;
}

public int getCountByItem(String id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String Get = "select count(*) from Records where item = '"+id+"'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Get ,null);
    int price = cursor.getCount();
    return price;
}
```

Here is a link to the graph library
 [link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

I used this video to explain [Video Explain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xd_meyCAnWI&list=PLc2rvfiptPSR7NliWRLwweX55XwrsrTOO&index=13)

Comment: please don't edit your question with code that fixes the issue, as anyone else looking at the issue will be confused as there would appear to be no problem. If you have more information specifically in regard to the question you should edit the question  and include an explanation of the edit. However, if the problem has been resolved and you are facing subsequent issues you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `getPriceDate` method you appear to be incrementing x outside of the loop so x will not be increased.

You currently have :-

```
    while (x < count) {
        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                //assuming price is an integer
                price1[x] = c.getInt(0);//edit 4

                price11 = price11 + price1[x];
                // use these strings as you want
            }
        }
    }
    x++; //<<<<<< not in the while loop so won't be actioned.
```

Change it to :-

```
    while (x < count) {
        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                //assuming price is an integer
                price1[x] = c.getInt(0);//edit 4

                price11 = price11 + price1[x];
                // use these strings as you want
            }
        }
        x++; //<<<<<< Moved to inside the loop
    }
```

Comment: thanx!!! Could you please help me and tell me where I was wrong? I'm trying to create a graph with all the expenses of the last month ... but for some reason I came across a problem that it does not print anything to me! I edited the message with the revised code and some explanations

Comment: It may not print anything if there is nothing to print i.e. if the extracted cursor is empty. If so, your loop test would equate to  `while (0 < 0)` (i.e. x is initially 0 and if the cursor is empty the count will be 0).  I'd suggest adding Log.d("C COUNT","Numer of Rows extracted is " + Integer.toString(c.getCount());' after `c = db.getCursorByDate(id);`. If it's 0 then the cursor isn't extracting any data. So you'd need to find out why. If it's greater than 0 then the issue is elsewhere. That's an example of a debugging method.